# is there a reason to revoke write permission for executables in /usr/bin

Tags: permissions, executable

I have encountered a package which installs its binaries with permission `555` instead of usual `755` in `/usr/bin`, i.e. prohibiting writing for everyone. I do not understand the reason for doing so... Can assume that they want to add extra security, but not sure.

My question is as follows: can having permissions `555` for binaries in `/usr/bin` lead to any problems with such a binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is owned by the root user, permissions *normally* don't matter, the root user will be able to do anything with the file regardless.

If the file is owned by a non-root user, then 555 could be pertinent to prevent the owner of the file rewriting the file (which could allow to e.g. embed malware or run some code).

Comment: Can you, please, clarify two points? 1. is there ever a reason to make non-root user an owner of something, which is in '/usr/bin' or '/usr/local/bin'? and 2. for example, I am writing a daemon, which will reside in '/usr/bin'... Will it not create problems, when I call `make install` to re-install the serivce, because I have no rights to write?

Comment: SetUID bit could be the reason: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#SUID This is all in a ton of manuals and howtos on the Internet, please take your time.